# PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Estoy haciendo los CORS en SpringBoot y he tenido una serie de problemas que los he solucionado importando 1 dependencia.

El pom.xml:

```
  <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
      <!-- JPA Data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

           <!-- MySQL Connector-J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Tomcat embedded container -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

          <!-- Data REST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Y WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
package com.service.configure;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.service")

public class ServiciosConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //@Value("${usrRest}")
   // private String usrRest; 

    //@Value("${passRest}")
   // private String passRest; 
    //@PropertySource("file:${ruta_properties}")

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic().and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override

    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
    }



    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER");

    }

}
```

Al principio me daba error, pero lo solucioné con

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

Porque decía que tenía problemas con uno de los imports...

El caso es que después de añadir esa dependencia, actualizar el proyecto, ejecuto y obtengo :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:236) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:196) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:86) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:166) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
```

En la web:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jul 04 08:51:28 CEST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
```

Comment: Al parecer no le estas pasando el id. ¿Lo pudiste resolver?

Comment: cambie toda la configuración del proyecto, poniéndola en otra versión del pom

Answer (score 0):

Remplaza

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER");

}
```

por

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());

}
@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user =
            User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                    .username("admin")
                    .password("admin")
                    .roles("USER")
                    .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
```

Explicación:

El `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` se encarga de la creación de usuarios por tí mediante su constructor:

```
 public InMemoryUserDetailsManager(UserDetails... users) {
    UserDetails[] var2 = users;
    int var3 = users.length;

    for(int var4 = 0; var4 < var3; ++var4) {
        UserDetails user = var2[var4];
        this.createUser(user);
    }

}
```